# SMTP Gmail timing out

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail

Not sure why this is happening. Every where I've search tells me that i'm doing this right. But every time I try and send the mail, it times out on the `smtpserver.Send(mail)`

```
private void emailReport(string email_address,int begDatabaseCount, int endDatabaseCount)
        {
            SmtpClient smtpserver = new SmtpClient();
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            smtpserver.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpserver.Port = 465;
            smtpserver.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";           
            smtpserver.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mtaylor@atr.com", "password");
            smtpserver.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("mtaylor@atr.com", "ATR Reports");
            mail.To.Add(email_address);
            mail.Subject = "FNAS Report - " + DateTime.Now;
            mail.Body += "<u><b>FNAS Report for " + DateTime.Now + "</u></b>" + "\r\n \r\n";
            mail.Body += "Beginning Database Count - " + begDatabaseCount + "\r\n" + "\r\n";
            mail.Body += "End Database Count - " + endDatabaseCount + "\r\n" + "\r\n";
            mail.Body += "<b>Total Imported Orders = " + (endDatabaseCount - begDatabaseCount) + "<b>" + "\r\n" + "\r\n";
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            smtpserver.Send(mail);
        }
```

Port 465 =  Time Out after 1 minute

Port 587 = "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This thread helped me. I'm not sure why this code worked and mine wasn't.

[Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

var fromAddress = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com", "From Name");
var toAddress = new MailAddress("to@example.com", "To Name");
const string fromPassword = "fromPassword";
const string subject = "Subject";
const string body = "Body";

var smtp = new SmtpClient
           {
               Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
               Port = 587,
               EnableSsl = true,
               DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
               UseDefaultCredentials = false,
               Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
           };
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
                     {
                         Subject = subject,
                         Body = body
                     })
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: it works for me too, while the rest didn't..

I don't really know wy either

Comment: You need to have Credentials and UeDefaultCredentials in this order.  The code in the post had it reversed.

Answer (score 10):

As @kostyan said, the right port is 587, but to authenticate you need to allow access from less secure apps in your gmail account.
Try it [here](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

It worked for me, hope it helps..

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure about the port, in my code I have it as 587, otherwise looks similar and it works.

Comment: I believe that the port number for Gmail should be 587

Comment: When I use port 587 I get this error "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. " Even though I have EnableSSL = true

Comment: only other difference I see is this line you're missing
smtpserver.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

Comment: Just added the DeliveryMethod in there - still no luck.

Comment: I was having problems to send a email with gmail smtp server, and it worked when i changed the port form 465 to 587, wich is strange, because on the gmail help page they say port 465.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that when I tried to spoof the sender address using google smtp (for instance, using FromAddress as something other than the name of my gmail account) I was getting either authentication error messages or simply timing out.