# Gmail sending email timing out

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gmail, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to send an email by gmail but this code isn't working, gives connection time out error. If I make the port '587' it gives this error:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at

```
        string email = // email
        string password = // password
        string smtp = // smtp.gmail.com
        int port = // 465 

        var from = new MailAddress(email, "");
        var to = new MailAddress(message.Destination);

        var client = new SmtpClient()
        {
            Host = smtp,
            Port = port,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(email, password)
        };

        var mail = new MailMessage(from, to)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body,
            IsBodyHtml = true
        };

        return client.SendMail(mail);
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to smtp.gmail.com:465 from the computer where you're running you program in some other way? For example, by telnet to this address/port.

Comment: It doesn't work on Azure too.

Answer (score 0):

I have used very similar code to yours in the past and it worked, but the port number I used was 587.
This is my code:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient
                                    {
                                        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                                        Port = 587,
                                        EnableSsl = true,
                                        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                                        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                                        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("gmail_login", "gmail_password")
                                    };
using( var message = new MailMessage("your_emailAddress", "destination_Email")
                              {
                                  Subject ="subject",
                                  Body = "body"
                              })
client.Send(message);
```

If you are logging from a new destination/timezone you should first log in through the web browser and confirm that it is you :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently posted another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932981/smtp-gmail-timing-out/27990543#27990543) that addresses this situation:

> You need to make sure that the email account that you're using allows
>   access from less secure apps.
>
> Simply change a security setting from your account.
>
> Try it [here](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)