# SMTP works in Linux but not on Mac

Tags: python, linux, macos, email, smtp

When I run the following code in Linux, it sends, the email, however, in Mac, it fails to run at line server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", "587")

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import subprocess as s
import sys
import os

def send_email(predicted_change, sentiment, coin, toaddr):
     fromaddr = "****@gmail.com"
     msg = MIMEMultipart()
     msg['From'] = fromaddr
     msg['To'] = toaddr
     msg['Subject'] = "Predicted Price Change Of " + coin

     body = "The sentiment of the last 60 minutes for " + coin + " is : " + 
     sentiment + " - The predicted change in price is : " + predicted_change
     msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
     server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", "587")
     server.starttls()
     server.ehlo()
     server.login(fromaddr, "****")
     text = msg.as_string()
     print(text)
     server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
     server.quit()
     print("Over")
```

I get this error

```
 socket.error: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: Smtplib works pretty good on Mac, even the line `server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", "587")`.

Comment: I get this error
     socket.error: [Errno 60] Operation timed out

Comment: @HaveAnAverageDay Leaving this closed, but this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932981/smtp-gmail-timing-out gives probably the real reason it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, none of the solutions to that question seems to work for me. Have already allowed access from less secure apps.